# MDM with dual boot - private volume with FileVault

Tags: filevault, dual-boot, mdm, automated-device-enrollment

I will soon have to follow an enrolment process with the company MacBook pro (16'' 2021) I've been using (both for home and work activities).

I'd like to continue using the current volume for home activities so I created a second APFS volume where I installed a second MacOS for work related activities and the enrolment.

Even though FileVault is enabled on my home volume, I can access its content from the new volume. I don't understand this…

What approach would you recommend to prevent admins from the work volume to be able to see files and apps from the home volume?

Comment: I don’t have a way to test, but I ran across [this document](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/manage-filevault-with-mdm-dep0a2cb7686/web) when researching your question. Hopefully it gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: There is none.  If they own the machine, you should not have personal content on it in the first place.  If nothing else, tomorrow they walk up to you and say "gimmie!" and take the laptop out of your hands, what would you do?